# Add Menu to 404 Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cms, 404-page, 404

I want to add the menu and other elements to my 404 page in Magento 2. Can anyone tell me where the index/no-route takes its layout instructions from? As I cannot seem to find them?

Presumably if it's removing the menu automatically it is a layout update somewhere along the line.

There is nothing in the CMS page layout update function, and nothing changes if I update the layout template in the same section.

Comment: You have CMS Page "404 Not Found" title and inside you can change what you want

Comment: Yes I see the page, but for some reason the top menu (in fact any of the header) is not outputted on the page. As if a layout update is blocking it...